# User profile field used to filter view?

Tags: views

OKay - I'm either brain fading or truly confused (probably both).

I need to filter a view based on the value of a field, but in a unique way. The content type (task) has a field (location) which is also used on the user profile. I need the view to only show those tasks which have the same value as the logged in user in that field. What the *&% am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

may be this will help you
[views_conditional](https://drupal.org/project/views_conditional)

How to use Views Conditional in your Views:

- Create a view. Add some fields under "FIELDS".
- Click on "ADD" next to fields. Scroll down to "Views: Views Conditional", probably found near the bottom of the list.
- Add and configure fields
- Choose a field to run a condition against, and provide values accordingly.
- Save, views conditional handles the logic and returns as specified.
  use replacement variables

[image: Views conditional image]